# My pod is not outgoing outside cluster / public

Tags: kubernetes, networkx

My nodes have 1 interface, set proxy for access public.
I use calico for cni. Problem is pod running not outgoing to public. From host, i accessed public
What is problem anh resolve?

I try from pod perform traceroute. Result is stuck node hop

Comment: i think problem relate to proxy and iptables nat but i no idea fix it